# How to scroll an element inside parent when a fixed element passes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a bit too tricky for my jQuery / javascript knowledge so i'm sorry to say i haven't really tried anything yet. I need some hints to get pointed in the right direction!

The problem is that i have a fixed element on my page, and when scrolling down this element will enter different wrappers, and while in that wrapper i need a smaller child element to "snap" to my fixed element and while it's in the element.

Kind of hard to explain, i made a static mockup here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ycmYc/

When "fixed cart button" reaches a price, i need it to attach and scroll with the cart button as long as it's inside the prices "product-div". When it leaves and enters the next the price should stay in the bottom of it's product and then snap to the cart-button again when the users is reaching it by scrolling up.

Well, again, sorry for not having tried anything but i am lost. If i had to do this without any help i think i'd go with waypoints.js but it feels far from optimal.

Any help MUCH APPRECIATED!

The fixed element will always have the same position, so i guess offset from the browser top could be used instead of keeping track of it's position. Always something ;)

Update:

Been working on it myself, and got it working downwards but not upwards:

Should clarify what i mean:

http://retype.se/temp/scrolltest/test.html

When scrolling by the price, it joins the button downwards and snaps loose when leaving the container. My problem now is making it snap to it and scroll back to its original position when scrolling upwards :)

Comment: And what with - when *button* is initially over the "yellow" area?

Comment: Nothing should  happen until _button_ reaches the first price... then the price should snap and scroll with button while inside prices parent .product container :)

Comment: It's really important to know if the `.product` heights will be all the same or will they be variable

Comment: I'm afraid they will be variable... all products will probably be the same but will vary depending on the screen size since they will contain images 100% wide ;) So no, theres no possiblity to count pixels from top :/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ycmYc/39/

only result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ycmYc/39/show/light/

[image]

updated:

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ycmYc/93/

only result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ycmYc/93/show/light/

Comment: Pretty good, I like the second example. Looks like you need to only allow the price box to follow the button while it's inside it's allotted area as it were though. (And stop at the bottom until you scroll back up).

Comment: Yep, thats my problem now Thor84no, thought this question was dead so i managed to accomplish this by myself with waypoints.js. However, having it work in both scroll directions and leave off the price at the bottom of each area is tougher than expected. Great work however songsunkyun!

Answer (score 0):

this is just a brainfart, but maybe it gets things going (sry, dont have time for a fiddle). But I got the idea, of maybe trying to cheat optically.

What I mean is, to calculate the absolute positions of all price divs, hide them, and when the cart div reaches that position by scrolling, show the price div for x amount of pixel scrolling (or via z-indexes by making backgrounds, not sure what suits you better).

Hope this helps a bit, maybe I get time today to script it out.

Answer (score 0):

It kinda depends on the constraints. You can detect the scroll position of a window with: 
`window.pageYOffset` or `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.

If the divs are all the same size you could easily calculate which div the button is over and the `position: fixed` the price next to it.